# reference a field on unrelated object in soql

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have 3 objects- Case, Contact, & Purchases (custom).I am writing a SOQL query on Purchases that needs a field from Contact. There is a Master-Detail relationship from Purchases to Case (field name Case__c), and a Lookup Relationship from Case to Contact (field name ContactId). Besides this, Purchases and Case aren't related.

I've been trying the following but I keep getting `Didn't understand relationship 'ContactId__c' in field path.` errors, could anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

```
[SELECT Case__r.ContactId__r.Fixed_Wholesaling_Channel__c FROM Purchases__c]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__r` is used for traversing *custom* relationships, not standard ones. `Case.ContactId` is a standard relationship, which you traverse by removing the `Id` suffix:

```
SELECT Case__r.Contact.Fixed_Wholesaling_Channel__c FROM Purchases__c
```

Comment: life saver!! thanks so much